# How to delete specific key including between '2002' and '2006'?

Tags: sql, sas

Here is the exam data table that I would like to process here:

-origin data

| STU_ID | STU_KEY | STU_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2002123 | A120 |
| 124 | 2002124 | A120 |
| 125 | 2002125 | A120 |
| 126 | 2002126 | A120 |
| 127 | 2002127 | A120 |
| 128 | 2003123 | A120 |
| 129 | 2003124 | A120 |
| 130 | 2004123 | A120 |
| 131 | 2005123 | A120 |
| 132 | 2006123 | A120 |
| 133 | 2007123 | A120 |
| 134 | 2008321 | A120 |

I want to delete rows of specific key including between '2002' and '2006' using code of SAS proc sql.

-result data

| STU_ID | STU_KEY | STU_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 133 | 2007123 | A120 |
| 134 | 2008321 | A120 |

```
 '''error code'''
 PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE a.not_2002_2006 as
 SELECT t.STU_ID, 
        t.STU_KEY, 
        t.STU_CODE
 FROM a.stu as t
 WHERE t.STU_KEY NOT LIKE '2002%' 
 and t.STU_KEY NOT LIKE '2003%' 
 and t.STU_KEY NOT LIKE '2004%' 
 and t.STU_KEY NOT LIKE '2005%' 
 and t.STU_KEY NOT LIKE '2006%'
 GROUP BY t.STU_ID;
 QUIT;
```

Let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Is this the error you're facing `LIKE operator requires character operands` ?

Comment: What data type `STU_KEY` is?

Comment: I already finished solving the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting the `LIKE operator requires character operands` error. If that is the case, this is due to the fact that your `STU_KEY` is a numeric column. Tweak the where statement to use the like operator with a character column using the [PUT](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n0mlfb88dkhbmun1x08qbh5xbs7e.htm) function.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as select stu_id, stu_key, stu_code 
    from have 
    where put(stu_key, 7.) like '2007%' 
        or put(stu_key, 7.) like '2008%'
    group by stu_id;
quit;
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I solved the problem because of your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> You could try with SUBSTR:
> https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212267.htm

```
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE a.not_2002_2006 as
 SELECT t.STU_ID, 
        t.STU_KEY, 
        t.STU_CODE
 FROM a.stu as t
 WHERE  substr(t.STU_KEY,1,4) >=2007 
 GROUP BY t.STU_ID;
 QUIT;
```

Comment: I solved the problem because of your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In case STU_KEY is a number, treat it as a number and define your conditions as numbers.

To get the records between 2002000 and 2006999:

```
WHERE
  STU_KEY >= 2002000 AND STU_KEY < 2007000 /* 2002000-2006999 */
```

To get the records which are not in the above range

```
WHERE
  STU_KEY < 2002000 OR STU_KEY >= 2007000
```

To get the ones greater than 2007000

```
WHERE
  STU_KEY >= 2007000 /* 2007000+ */
```

Comment: I solved the problem because of your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Plutos Welcome! Do you mind sharing your solution to the problem? You can do so by answering your question here, so other stumbling in this question will have more to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Some easy ways,

If character variable

- `STU_KEY between "2002" and "2007"`
- `substr(STU_KEY,1,4) between "2002" and "2006"`

If numeric variable

- `int(STU_KEY/1000) between 2002 and 2006`

Comment: I solved the problem because of your answer. Thank you very much.